# if statement in anchor

Tags: php, wordpress, anchor

I am trying add an if statement to an anchor like so.

```
     <div class="box-button">
            <a href="
            <?php $header_button = of_get_option('header_text'); ?>
                        <?php if($header_button){?>
                      <?php echo of_get_option('header_text'); ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
        #                                   
        <?php } ?>

            " class="button">Connect Now</a>
        </div>
```

I can click the button on the homepage and I will get linked to "#" so it is as if wordpress doesn't recognize as a theme option. Is my syntax the problem?

Comment: Why would you not just `echo $header_button` instead of repeating the `of_get_option('header_text')`?

Comment: Why do you open and close your php on every line in there without adding anything in between at least?  Just open once, do all your code, and then close at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can do the logic outside the html and then insert the result into the href

```
<?php 
$header_button = of_get_option('header_text');

$link = (!empty($header_button)?$header_button:'#');
?>

<div class="box-button">
    <a href="<?php echo $link;?>" class="button">Connect Now</a>
</div>
```